# iOS 8/7 keyboard swipe up menu: no control center access

Tags: ios, iphone, control-center

How can I access the iOS 8 Control Center swipe-up menu while the keyboard is active?

Comment: I'd try the usuals ... Reboot; or in iTunes, sync, backup, restore.

Answer (score 1):

It should be accessible while the keyboard is active. (Source: I can do it now.) Just start your finger below the screen (like on the Home button) and swipe upwards quickly, not lingering on the space bar or any key.

Comment: Trying now: 8υιγηшшщотм1"97)ξυθξηηι. <-- As I swiped up the keyboard to open Command Center, I could see the letters magnify as I passed over each; usually it would type the one I ended on, otherwise the language would change or voice dictation would start.

Comment: ¡Aha!! It was the way I swipe that is the problem: fast and flick-esque. When I traverse the entire keyboard deliberately on a similarly erratic swipe, it in deed appears! I have also found that slow swiping-up shows the menu almost every time, and traversing the entire length of the keyboard is not necessary.